# Sub-domain Getting Issue with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, redirect

I have a domain "**example.com**" and i use following redirection code to redirect it to www in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it is working fine until i generate a sub-domain with that domain like "**abc.example.com**" but it's getting conflicts with htaccess and redirecting the sub-domain to "**www.abc.example.com/abc/**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|abc)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: what if i had 2 sub-domains? what should i do than?

Comment: You can use: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|abc|other|etc)\.`. It's a bit more complicated to accept all

Comment: Unless you use a single domain, you can use: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com`